# get distinct value count in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table in MySQL as below.

### id   |  number  |  name  | type

111    |  123     |  XYZ   | bar

222    |  234     |  ABC   | restaurants

111    |  007     |  PKA   | food

111    |  123     |  XYZ   | bar

333    |  123     |  XYZ   | bar

Now what I would like to get is total size of number which is having unique id. Meaning in my case **111** and **333** have same number that is **123**. So the total count for number 123 is 2. Here I don't want to count 111 again as you can see that 111 came twice for the number 123 but I don't want to add it in the total size as its already there in the count. So i want the unique id's count which is having same number.

**OUTPUT i want from the query is :-**

**123 (XYZ) - 2 (There are total 3 entry but 111 id is repeated for number 123 and I don't want duplicated one. So I want to take both id and number in consideration while getting the count.)**

**234 (ABC) - 1**

**007 (PKA) - 1**

I used the Group By for finding duplicate values but didn't get the proper output as per my requirements. Any help or suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You can post edit your question to include your expected output from the query result as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select number, count(distinct id)
from your_table
group by number
```

Answer (score 1):

also possible:

```
select id, number, name, type, 
       count(distinct id) over (partition by number) numOfDistictIds
from table
order by number
```